# why an error occurs in the 'react-code-blocks' library?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm working on a project with Typescript, React... I encountered an error while using the 'react-code-blocks' library.

I've got the following structure for the container component:

```js
interface ICodeBlockProps {
  codes: string[];
}

function CodeBlock({ codes = ['', ''] }: ICodeBlockProps) {

  return (
    <CopyBlock
       theme={hybrid}
       text={codes[0]}
       codeBlock
       copied
       wrapLongLines={false}
       language="jsx"
    />
  );
}
```

[error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lbq4.png)

```js
Type '{ theme: { ... }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ExecutionProps & RefAttributes<({ theme, text, codeBlock, customStyle, onCopy, ...rest }: CopyBlockProps) => Element>'.
  Property 'text' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ExecutionProps & RefAttributes<({ ... }: CopyBlockProps) => Element>'.ts(2322)
```

If you remove the 'text' prop, the same error will occur in other props.

When I first encountered the error I thought it was because I wasn't passing in an interface defining my props, but I created that (as you can see above) and it still doesn't work. I'm wondering, is there something I'm missing?

I also checked the 'CopyBlock.d.ts' file in that library. I am curious why an error occurs even though the types match.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Theme } from '../types';
export interface CopyBlockProps {
    theme: Theme;
    text: string;
    codeBlock: boolean;
    copied: boolean;
    wrapLongLines: boolean;
    onCopy: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
    language: string;
    customStyle?: {};
    [x: string]: any;
}
export default function CopyBlock({ theme, text, codeBlock, customStyle, onCopy, ...rest }: CopyBlockProps): React.JSX.Element;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of buried, but someone mentions the error here:
https://github.com/rajinwonderland/react-code-blocks/issues/16#issuecomment-1632761670

> The types for these components seem off (missing partial designation).
> When you try to use a component, it tells you all these optional props
> are required...

I tried adding all of the required fields and it still doesn't fix the error.
My best bet is:
`import("styled-components").ExecutionProps` and `import("react").RefAttributes<typeof CopyBlock>`

Both use a "theme", but it's optional for styled-components and not CopyBlock, and it is using the ExecutionProps in typescript when passing it through, so it won't fulfill the required theme of CodeBlocks.

No easy fix for now.